# Save byte to file with php

Tags: php, file

I have a c# program with some bitmap datatypes which i would like to upload to my web server with HTTP.
So i am thinking of converting the bitmap to the datatype bytes and then post it as text to the server, the sever would then save it as a image file.

How would i do this in PHP?

I am guessing something like this? but then how would i specify the save path location?

```
    <?php
    $data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
           . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
           . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
           . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($data));
```