# Getting Google Docs document Apps Script for accessing in server

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-apps

I have created a sidebar for Google Docs and made tweaks on the document. Now I am at a point that I want to get the document and send it to my server via ajax; however I couldn't find any way to achieve this. The only way I found is getting the document as HTML and re-creating it in the server from that html. However it won't be able to re-create the document just as it is - as 100%.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Maybe getting a public "download url" or "download as pdf" (even better) just like Google Drive offers so that I can download the docx from my server?

---

One other way I found is saving the file to Google Drive but then it asks user for Google Drive scopes.

Is there any other way beside that too? What is the best way?

Comment: You could call the server-side GAS function using google.script.run. Inside that function, get the blob for the file and send the document to your server as Byte array.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: @AntonDementiev Can you please add more details? As far as I understand, in my `.gs` file,  I should use something like this: `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBlob().getBytes()` and send it to my server? But how will recreate the file on my server which is php? I am pretty lost. I'd be grateful for your help

Comment: Alright, sorted it. I got the bytes array in my server. Let's see where it goes with php

Comment: I don't have a clue about PHP, but his might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201587/save-byte-to-file-with-php

Comment: @AntonDementiev I have a question. How is this guy's looks like a string and my one looks like an array? Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: You may find this helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 Google Apps Script provides methods for encoding binary data with the Utilities class https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities